# Strange referers in Apache logfiles: empty string and what looks like MySQL code

Tags: mysql, r, apache, http-referer, logfile

I've read my logfiles into R, and when I look at the referer there are some strange entries:

```
> logs <- read.table("logfile")
> referer <- data.frame(table(logs$referer))
> head(referer, 2)
Var1              Freq
1                  157
2             - 250290
```

Apache uses a dash (`-`) to denote a missing referer. That's row 2. So what does the empty string (``) in row 1 mean? As I see it, that could only happen if Apache "forgot" to write the referer to the logfile.

Here is one of the 157 entries with an empty referer string (I have anonymized the client ip and my website URL):

```
173.244.xxx.xxx - - [17/Apr/2018:08:07:46 +0200] "GET /feeds/atom.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 18820 www.my-website.com "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36; +collection@infegy.com" "-"
```

But the most mysterious referers look like this:

```
554fcae493e564ee0dc75bdf2ebf94caads|a:2:{s:3:"num";s:280:"*/ union select 1,0x272f2a,3,4,5,6,7,8,0x7b24617364275d3 ...
```

I have cut off the string at the end (it goes on for quite a bit longer), because I don't know if it contains sensitive information. I have about 20 visits with referers like this, all from the same client ip, most of them requesting resources that do not exist on my server, such as `//user.php` and `//cm.php`.

It seems to me that these are, at least in part, MySQL queries. `a:2:{s:3:"num";s:459:"` is the beginning of a serialized array. I use this format to store some data from a web form in a MySQL database. But this processing happens serverside and is never sent to the user's browser. And how does a MySQL query end up as a referer anyway? I can understand that someone might try to enter MySQL code into a webform, but that doesn't make that part of a referer.

Any explanations would be nice.

Comment: There's an R package — [`webreadr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webreadr/vignettes/Introduction.html) designed specifically for Apache log files. I'd suggest using that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an attack against internal infrastructure. Many organizations use centralized systems to ingest logs and then use reporting infrastructure to support querying logs. Developers are fairly bad at designing secure systems and the SQL in a `Referer` field is trying to take advantage of that.

Attackers can also try to store snippets in `Referer` fields and then make use of it in other types of attacks.

So long as you aren't using poorly crafted software to query logs you should be fine.

This — https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/sql-injection-http-headers/ — provides some further information.

Also, as noted in the comment, consider user [`webreadr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webreadr/vignettes/Introduction.html) to read in web server log files.

And, upon further review, this appears to be a campaign by an attacker group looking to compromise "Ecshop" content management system (https://github.com/SecWiki/CMS-Hunter/tree/master/Ecshop/ecshop2.x_code_execute). If you are running that you may want to triple check your server.

Comment: Thank you. Any additonal thoughts on what that empty string referer means or how it may have come about?

Comment: You're using `read.table` so it may be a "` `" or even a non-breaking space.

Comment: I checked the original logfile. There is actually nothing inbetween the double quotes. But thank you.

Comment: "nothing" can be a "space" vs a missing field (I kinda do this for a living)

Comment: I understand, but there is really nothing. In a hex editor it looks like this: `2222`, that's two double quotes with nothing inbetween. So "nothing" here really means nothing. No space or other "invisible" char.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a SQL injection attempt. The logs won't show if the SQL attempt is successful.

While this would normally show in a URL field, there's no reason it couldn't show up in a HTTP referrer field in your logs.

Comment: Thank you. Any additonal thoughts on what that empty string referer means or how it may have come about?

Comment: An empty refer string will come about if someone clicks on a link, or types in a URL, or has a plugin/privacy settings the prevents its transmittal, or is a script.